# how to remove older informatica session log file for each session using unix scripting

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I am new Unix scripting, I have scenario that i need to remove older session log file for each session in informatica log folder.

I have session log file presented in /xxx/xxx path like below

```
session_201809.log
session_201709.log
session_201609.log
session1_201809.log
session1_201709.log
session2_201809.log
session2_201709.log
```

I need to remove `session_201709.log`, `session_201609.log`, `session1_201709.log`, `session2_201709.log` 
Since its older log file for each session

Comment: Why not working with `find -mtime`? You don't look at the filename, but the last modification date.

Comment: Let me try inthis way

Comment: Its not solved my problem cz I need to get latest run of the each session.. Its giving latest run from all of the session..

Like below
if i have 
session_201809.log
session_201709.log
session_201609.log
session1_201809.log
session1_201709.log
session2_201809.log
session2_201709.log

Then I need to remove session_201709.log, session_201609.log, session1_201709.log, session2_201709.log from my folder

Answer (score 1):

This shouldn't be a unix use case but an Informatica session configuration one. In workflow manager, go to each of your sessions and change the setting 'Save session logs by' from 'Timestamp' to 'Session runs' and change the number of runs setting to 1. That way the session will overwrite its logs on each run making your unix script redundant. (Of course it poses a problem when you want to analyze an old failed run but your current use case doesn't seem to worry about this).

You will have to clear out the old session logs manually once... whether you need a script for that is your call